# Firestore Rules for Blog Website

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple blog website where everyone can view the posts, but only admins can edit them.

The posts collection documents look like:

```
{
  title:"Hello World",
  body:"Hello Brian"
},
{
  title:"Gumdrops",
  body:"Goody, goody gumdrops"
},
```

The admins collection documents look like:

```
{
  email:"josh@email.com"
},
{
  email:"steve@email.com"
}
```

My Cloud Firestore Rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{post} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/admins/$(admin)).data.email == request.auth.token.email;
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error `Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

On the client side I am using AngularFire2, my code for that looks so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

export interface Post {
  id?: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent {

  private postsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
  public posts:any;

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    public authService: AuthService
  ) {
    this.postsCollection = afs.collection<Post>('posts');

    this.posts = this.postsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });
  }

  addPost(post) {
    this.postsCollection.add(post).then((ret) => {
    console.log('post added');
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code that raises that error?

Comment: I have no problem reading, and when I change my rule to 'allow write' it works too.

Comment: are you using `push keys`  as keys for admin users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I `FINALLY` got it!

I had the firestore rule wrong. I created a collection called `users` instead. 
The `id` is the users email address, and it has an `admin` field set to `true`

Then the following rule only allows administrators listed in the users collection to make changes.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.token.email)).data.admin == true;
    }
  }
}
```

Yay!